# 301 redirection for moving site to another CMS

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, redirect

I need 301 redirection rule for migrating CMS on site.

On old CMS I have URL structure like this:

I wish is to move my site to another CMS and to have all old (or most) URLs with 301 redirect to new pages.

Category url on old CMS:

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/page/2/

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name-some-category-suffix/

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name-some-category-suffix/page/2/

Post urls on old CMS.

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name-some-category-suffix/some-post-name.jpg.html

and one add-on page for every post like:

www.my-site-name.com/full-size/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name-some-category-suffix/some-post-name.jpg-some-words-here.html

---

Category url on new CMS:

I have "**category_url**" as category base (after domain name), also I wish to remove "**-some-category-suffix**" from category, and subcategory (if any).

For category URLs to:

add "**category_url/**" after domain name

remove "**-some-category-suffix**" from category, and any subcategories

to redirect to URL like this:

www.my-site-name.com/category_url/category-name/

www.my-site-name.com/category_url/category-name/page/2/

---

Post urls on new CMS.

I have for example "**category-url**" as post base (after domain name). Please note difference between category base "category_url" and post base "category-url".

For post page to:

remove "**-some-category-suffix**" from category, and any subcategories

rename "**.jpg.html**" to "**.html**"

to redirect to URL like this:

www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html

---

For post add-on page to:

remove "**-some-category-suffix**" from category, and any subcategories

rename "**full-size**" to "**category-url**"

rename "**.jpg-**" to "**.html-?**"

remove ending "**.html**" (after "-some-words-here")

to redirect to URL like this:

www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html-?some-words-here

---

Summary.

Category from:

www.my-site-name.com/category-name**-some-category-suffix**/

to:

www.my-site-name.com/**category_url**/category-name/

Post from:

www.my-site-name.com/category-name**-some-category-suffix**/subcategory-name**-some-category-suffix**/some-post-name**.jpg.html**

to:

www.my-site-name.com/**category-url**/category-name/subcategory-name/some-post-name**.html**

Post add-on page from:

www.my-site-name.com/**full-size**/category-name**-some-category-suffix**/subcategory-name**-some-category-suffix**/some-post-name**.jpg-**some-words-here**.html**

to:

www.my-site-name.com/**category-url**/category-name/subcategory-name/some-post-name**.html-?**some-words-here

Any help would be great, if rewrite rules are not possible for all URL types than please for some of them.

---

I tried this:

```
#For post page URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*).jpg.html(.*)$ /category-url/$1$2.html$3 [L,R=301]

#For post add-on page URLs
RewriteRule ^full-size/(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*).jpg-(.*).html(.*)$ category-url/$1$2.html-?$3$4 [L,R=301]

#Category URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*)$ /category_url/$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

It works, if there is just one category level, it removes just last "-some-category-suffix".

Output examples

For post pages

www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html

or for post add on page

www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html-?some-words-here

or for category

www.my-site-name.com/category_url/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name/

I need little tweak of it to **remove all instance of "-some-category-suffix"** if more than one in URL.

If you can fix it, that would be nice.

Any advice, help?

Comment: ok, fine, we got the idea. Now tell us: what is your actual question here? Or is it just that you want someone else to do all your work? Show what you have tried so far and point out what is not working and why you have problems to understand why that fails.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha for reply. I tried with rewrite rule for add-on page firstly, I think it has most job for it.

**RewriteRule ^full-size/(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*).jpg-(.*).html(.*)$ category-url/$1$2.html-?$3$4 [L,R=301]**

It works great if there is just one category level, for subcategories it removes just last "-some-category-suffix".

www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html-?some-words-here

I am very new to this, so if you can correctly fix this and make other rules would be nice.

Comment: I improved my rewrite roles, but still, I need little help.

Comment: Fine, but still the same problem: unless you ask a clear and narrow question no one is going to sit down for hours and do your work for you. I myself feel thrown back by the sheer number of rules involved here. But at least one hint from me: i learned that (whyever) most users struggling with rewrite rules try to _guess_ what might be wrong and follow a strategy of trying around. Instead turn on rewrite logging (read the excellent documentation on mod_rewrite) and the engine actually tells you what is going on step by step. That way you can see at what point things go wrong.